# Polkadot.js wallet dosen't show methot section(transaction details) when making a transaction

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, polkadot-js-extension, wallet

When making a transaction we are supposed to see the transaction details under the method section but we only see method data

Wrong:
[image: when making a transaction we are supposed to see the transaction details under the method section]

Correct(you can see the method -> assetConversion..):
[image: correct method]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the polkadot extension has this feature, you can open an Issue [in the repository](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/issues) to decode the method and display the information in a more user friendly way.

In the meantime you can decode that value and see what method you are signing using the polkadotJS UI, going to the tab Extrinsic -> Decode and pasting that value ([here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics/decode)).

Comment: If you read the question again and take a look at the two screenshots i added you will see that it does exists, it actually has to exist since you have to see what method you are executing and what parameters you are sending, the issues here is that my colleagues wallet doesn't show the method with it's params at all which is very strange, this is only happening to one person, other people when the try to make a transaction it shows the method.

Comment: Any different with the versions you and yout colleague are using?